# Flutter crashing with just_audio package: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity"

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I am using just_audio package and the flutter app has started crashing.

```
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
E/AndroidRuntime(18755): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18755): Process: com.zenbition.zense_timer, PID: 18755
E/AndroidRuntime(18755): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.zenbition.zense_timer/com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.zenbition.zense_timer-YIaQtX7NxpYwWAO2yfHEHQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.zenbition
```

When the app loads, it crashes after 1 second.

Prior to crashing just_audio stopped playing sound (but wasn't throwing any errors).

I have removed and reinstalled just_audio and run flutter clean / flutter pub get with full restart, but can't fix the error:

Here is the full error code.

```
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk...
E/AndroidRuntime(18073): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18073): Process: com.zenbition.zense_timer, PID: 18073
E/AndroidRuntime(18073): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.zenbition.zense_timer/com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.zenbition.zense_timer-YIaQtX7NxpYwWAO2yfHEHQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.zenbition.zense_timer-YIaQtX7NxpYwWAO2yfHEHQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.zenbition.zense_timer-YIaQtX7NxpYwWAO2yfHEHQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.zenbition.zense_timer-YIaQtX7NxpYwWAO2yfHEHQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.zenbition.zense_timer-YIaQtX7NxpYwWAO2yfHEHQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.zenbition.zense_timer-YIaQtX7NxpYwWAO2yfHEHQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
E/AndroidRuntime(18073):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer, and was my silly mistake. Posting answer in case anyone does the same.

In the Activity Tag in the Android Manifest (android>app>src>main>AndroidManifest.xml) I had changed the android:name (as was going to use another audio package which required this step).

So to fix this error just needed to change back to android:name=".MainActivity".